# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to run a JAR file for the project, but the following error shows up :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

I tried to look for the class manually within my libraries, but the class was not present. It seems the specific class is not present in the current version of spring-boot-starter-web. Below is the POM for the project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I've searched for that class and it seems to be there: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.5.RELEASE try to add this dependency

Answer (score 1):

I added my project folder resources/META-INFO/spring.factories. After that, I got the same error above. I remove the folder and my project starts well!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following dependency :

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

The dependency `spring-boot-starter` includes the dependencies for logging `spring-boot-starter-logging`, which has the class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer`